# Way for new Mac touch bar to behave the same as the Old keyboard

Tags: macbook-pro, google-chrome, development, touch-bar

The new touch bar is not very good for people good at keyboard shortcuts and development.

I used to be able to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>F8</kbd> to get iTunes to play without giving it focus.

How can I get the <kbd>F10</kbd>,<kbd>F11</kbd> etc. keys to always display on Chrome without pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>, on touch bar Mac?

This makes debugging annoying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the system preferences go to "Keyboard". Select the "Shortcuts"-tab. Select "Function Keys" in the left menu. Click the + and add the applications where you want the F-keys to always show.

If you never want the touch bar but the old F-keys with brightness, volume backlight and so on. Go back to the "Keybard"-tab and select "Expanded Control Strip" in the "Touch Bar Shows" drop-down menu.